# JVMJ9VM035 Unable to allocate OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8, websphere-portal

Can you please let me know how to solve the below issue , it is getting while starting the websphere server.

> JVMJ9VM035 Unable to allocate OutOfMemoryError JVMDUMP039I Processing
>   dump event "abort", detail "" at 2015/05/25 12:24:17 - pl ease wait.
>   JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using
>   'C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\bin\cor e.20150525.122417.6468.0001.dmp'
>   in response to an event JVMDUMP010I System dump written to
>   C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\bin\core.20150525 .122417.6468.0001.dmp
>   JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using
>   'C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\bin\javac
>   ore.20150525.122417.6468.0002.txt' in response to an event JVMDUMP010I
>   Java dump written to C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\bin\javacore.201505
>   25.122417.6468.0002.txt JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using 'C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\bin\Snap.
>   20150525.122417.6468.0003.trc' in response to an event JVMDUMP010I Snap dump written to C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\bin\Snap.20150525.1
>   22417.6468.0003.trc JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "abort", detail "".

Answer (score 1):

add -XDump:none option in your jvm args through admin console and try [increasing jvm allocated memory](http://www.mkyong.com/websphere/how-to-increase-websphere-jvm-memory/) as well from console

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually i can't login  to admin console because server is stopped and not able to start the server due to this issue. I am getting this JVM dump in entire WebSphere server root.

Comment: you can go to server profile root directory and delete generated dump files. After that you can edit the jvm args by manually editing server.xml